# What is the work done by a magnetic field in helical motion?

Tags: magnetic-fields

If a particle is given vertical velocity and magnetic field is uniform in  x direction, then it follows helical path. Where does is vertical velocity goes if magnetic field don't do any work momentum in y direction must be conserved?

Comment: If there is only a magnetic field and the particle has no initial x-component of velocity, the particle follows a circular path in the yz plane, not a helical path. If there is an initial $v_x$ component, the path is a helix. $v_x$ is constant; $v_y$ and $v_z$ components vary but interchange such that $\frac12m(v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2)=\frac12mv^2$ is constant. eg $v_y$ is a maximum when $v_z=0$. Kinetic energy is conserved.